# With Australia is it better to settle in a coastal tile or near a river?

Tags: civilization-6

Playing with [Australia](http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Australian_(Civ6)) you have "Land Down Under", which gives +3 housing in coastal cities. I'm not sure if this is cumulative with housing from fresh water sources, or not.

So I would like to know the housing bonuses with Australia for:

1. coastal tile with no fresh water
2. inland tile with fresh water access, and
3. coastal tile with fresh water

Is there any other reason besides housing that could influence this decision?

Comment: Doesn't really matter. Everything in Australia is designed to kill you, no matter where you live in the country.

Comment: Fairly certain the +3 is on top of whatever you'd normally get since you can get a +1 or +3 based on water sources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Both**

It is best to have both fresh water and coast as Australia. Both fresh water (River, Lake, etc) and coast (Australia only) provide +3 Housing each. Having only one is still fine, but fresh water is no better or worse than a coastal only city.

[image: Confirmed]

Comment: So in the 3rd case (both) you'll have +6 Housing?

Comment: Yes, you should.

Comment: Played a match tonight as Australia to confirm my answer.